How to replicate SQL with sub grouped OR expressions in laravel
I am looking to implement a search function, that optionally includes the various fields that I have for my users to search on.
My code thusfar:
        $categories = $request->input('category'); // array(int)
        $textSearch = $request->input('text'); // string

        $query = Product::query();

        if(!is_null($categories)){
            //$query->selectSub();
            foreach($categories as $catId){
                $category = ShopCategory::find($catId);

                $query = $query->whereBelongsTo($category);//TODO
            }
        }
        if(!is_null($textSearch)){
            $query = $query->whereAny([
                'name',
                'description',
                'shortDescription',
            ],
                'like', '%'.$textSearch.'%');
        }

        $searchResults = $query->paginate(36);

My goal is to reach an SQL statement equivalent to:
SELECT * FROM products WHERE (shop_category_id = ? OR shop_category_id = ?) AND (/* text search LIKE */)
But thusfar, I end up with more of a :
SELECT * FROM products WHERE shop_category_id = ? AND shop_category_id = ? AND (/* text search LIKE */)
Where each of the category id's are ANDed as part of the overall query instead of ORed in a group.
I am aware of or*() query methods, but it is unclear how to properly group them for the desired effect instead of just ORing them along with the text search.
Edit: Based on the accepted answer, I landed on this:
            $mainQuery->where(function($query) use ($categories) {
                foreach ($categories as $catId) {
                    $category = ShopCategory::find($catId);
                    $query->orWhereBelongsTo($category);
                }
            });


You can wrap some where condition into a group by using the where function with a callback. Any condition applied on the builder, inside the callback, will be wrap in parathesis. For example:
Model::query()->where('condition1', 'value')->where(function($query) {
  // those where will be wrapped into ()
  $query->where('condition2', 'value')->orWhere('condition3', 'value');
})

Will give the following query:
SELECT *
FROM models
WHERE conditon1 = 'value'
  AND (condition2 = 'value'
       OR condition3 = 'value')

And since it doesn't matter if the first where is a OR or AND, you can put that into a loop without worring about the first OR:
$columns = [
 'column1', 
 'column2',
 'column3'
]

Model::query()->where('condition1', 'value')->query(function($query) use ($columns) {
  foreach($columns as $column) {
    $query->orWhere($column, 'value');
  } 
});

This query is dynamically generated and will return the follow SQL:
SELECT *
FROM models
WHERE condition1 = 'value'
  AND (column1 = 'value'
       OR column2 = 'value'
       OR column3 = 'value')

And since the "column conditions" are wrapped into a group, they won't interfere with the first condition.

This got me there, thanks.
